# Catch Exception thrown in gRPC ServerInterceptor

Tags: grpc-java

I have implemented a ServerInterceptor for my gRPC server that is responsible for authenticating all incoming requests. When the request doesn't have a valid token, the ServerInterceptor closes the call and throws an exception back to the client. Abbreviated code:

```
public class UserAuthenticationInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

  ...

  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
      Metadata metadata,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
    boolean canAuthenticateUser = authenticateUser(...);
    if (canAuthenticateUser) {
      // Pass request to gRPC server
      ...
    } else {
      // Reject request
      serverCall.close(
          Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("The provided Firebase token is invalid."),
          new Metadata());
      return new ServerCall.Listener() {};
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach will return an exception to the client. The pattern my gRPC server follows is to never throw an exception to the client, but respond with a valid message proto containing the error code.

Is it possible to catch this exception thrown by the ServerInterceptor and return a valid message in its place? I suppose that I could write a ClientInterceptor to handle such responses, but this defeats the purpose of the client not needing to be aware of such server-side exceptions.

A few *potential* approaches:

1. Implement a `ServerCall.Listener` that handles the exception (if possible?)
2. Forward unauthenticated requests to gRPC server and have the service respond with a message proto containing the error
3. (Last resort) Catch exception in ClientInterceptor

Comment: I think handling Unauthenticated response on the client is fine. Am I understanding this right that you want to always return the "OK" status from the server for any RPC ? Where do you want to place a valid message of an authentication failure in that case? You'll either need a field in every RespT for that or you'll have to put it in the metadata. And you'll still have to handle it on the client side. What is the benefit of never returning non-OK statuses? Also keep in mind that a gRPC client can emit it's own error statuses like "Deadline_Exceeded" in case of a timeout.

Comment: Right now I do have error fields in all RespT protos. You're correct, these errors still need to be handled on the client side. But (in my opinion) it's cleaner to handle errors based on an error_code field compared to an arbitrary number of exceptions that need to be parsed/etc...

Comment: That being said, if common practice using gRPC is to return the built in error status codes I'd be open to doing that instead. My concern with using error status codes is that they don't have enough of them to support the types of errors that my server might hit. Example: INVALID_ARGUMENT - What arg is invalid? What if I have multiple args? Is common practice to send the arg name in the metadata? This seems much more complex than an error embedded in the response proto...

Comment: There is a message available alongside the error code in the standard error model and arbitrary details in richer model (if you use protobuf you can rely on it). https://grpc.io/docs/guides/error/